# Find rows in Excel that do not have a corresponding in another worksheet

Tags: excel, lookup, vlookup

I've got two Excel-worksheets with different structures. The content is being updated every day by a SQL-data-connection and every worksheet contains more than 50k rows.

**Worksheet1 (Accounts payable)**

```
Company_No | Company_Name  | Vendor   | Amount | InvoiceDate | InvoiceNumber 
UK123      | ExampleComp   | UK788    | 200,00 | 01.02.2016  | 444555
UK123      | ExampleComp   | UK788    | 350,00 | 05.02.2016  | 111222
UK789      | TestComp      | US222    | 1000,00| 09.02.2016  | 456456
```

**Worksheet2 (Accounts receivable)**

```
Company_No | Company_Name  | Customer | Amount | InvoiceDate | InvoiceNumber 
UK788      | RandomComp    | 123      | 200,00 | 01.02.2016  | 444555
US222      | RandomComp    | US789    | 1000,00| 09.02.2016  | 456456
```

I need to check these two worksheets for missing postings of intercompany accounts. In this example I would like to return the following (because there is no corresponding post in Worksheet2):

```
Company_No | Company_Name  | Vendor   | Amount | InvoiceDate | InvoiceNumber 
UK123      | ExampleComp   | UK788    | 350,00 | 05.02.2016  | 111222
```

The amount and order of rows may vary - I need a result table that shows ONLY the entries WITHOUT a "partner". Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Basically you want to check if a Company_no in sheet1 exists in sheet2. Have you tried using VLOOKUP? You can achieve this using MATCH, IFERROR, and filtering the results.

Comment: As your given data `UK789      | TestComp      | US222    | 1000,00| 09.02.2016  | 456456` this is also not in `Worksheet2` So, what is the logic to get your desired result? Are you matching the invoice number only?

Comment: @nightcrawler23: I've been playing around with VLOOKUP on this end. Checking for a match of a company is not enough - I have to figure out how to perform a check for multiple criteria ()

Comment: @harun24hr: It is. These worksheets contain posts for accounts payable and receivable department. For this reason the first and third column are switched in these spreadsheets. I need to check if there is a post on the opposite site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new column in Worksheet1 write the following formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Worksheet2'!F:F,MATCH(F2,'Worksheet2'!F:F,0)),"No match")`

Copy it down across all rows. Where it will say "No match" is where there was no match found in worksheet2

edit: if you want to use multiple criteria just add the cells in the MATCH() part of the formula, like so:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Worksheet2'!F:F,MATCH(F2&E2&C2,'Worksheet2'!F:F&'Worksheet2'!E:E&'Worksheet2'!C:C,0)),"No match")`

You can add as many as you want

Comment: Thanks for your approach. But checking for the company number only is not enough. I have to check for multiple criteria like amount, invoicedate and invoicenumber as well because there can be several postings from one company to another.